# React how to connect JS file with HTML file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React JS file which renders the following:

```
React.render(
    <TreeNode node={tree} />,
    document.getElementById("tree")
);
```

I reference it from a HTML file in the following way:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/listTree/treenode.css">

<h3>It's <code>TreeNodes</code> all the way down</h3>
<p>Edit the <code>tree</code> variable to change the tree</p>
<div id="tree">
    <script src="/listTree/TreeNode.js"></script>
</div>

</html>
```

However, the contents of the JS file are not displayed.

I don't have experience in working with JavaScript.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

Your script is already selecting the `tree` div element.  So, there is no need to put a script tag *inside* of the div tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/listTree/treenode.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h3>It's <code>TreeNodes</code> all the way down</h3>
      <p>Edit the <code>tree</code> variable to change the tree</p>
      <div id="tree">
      </div>
      <script src="listTree/TreeNode.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

You are also missing the `<head>` and `<body>` html tags.

Further, if you want to render jsx in your React code, you need to add `<script>` tags for them as well (and `type="text/jsx"` as a tag attribute):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/listTree/treenode.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h3>It's <code>TreeNodes</code> all the way down</h3>
      <p>Edit the <code>tree</code> variable to change the tree</p>
      <div id="tree">
      </div>
      <script src="listTree/TreeNode.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

As a test to make sure your environment is working (and you don't just have a problem in your Component.  Try to replace the code inside `Treenode.js` with this:

```
React.render(
    <div>Testing...</div>,
    document.getElementById("tree")
);
```

Then, you have no external dependencies.  If you see `Testing...` rendered, you know that the environment is set up correctly.

Comment: I don't have any `build` file in my project. How do I create one?

Comment: I've added react files from a CDN.  You just need to reference from where you have react.js installed locally.

Comment: So, do I still need another reference? Because the code in the current format still doesn't work.

Comment: How are you importing `TreeNode`?  Where is that component coming from?

Comment: I've made an edit to help you make sure the environment is set up correctly.

Comment: As a side note, you *will* have to actually learn JavaScript to be productive with React ;)

Comment: Thank you. `TreeNode.js` is located in `/app/listTree/`, while `index.html` is located in `app/`.

Comment: After changing `Treenode.js`, it is displaying `Testing...`

Comment: Good.  So, the `<TreeNode />` that you are referencing in `TreeNode.js` (inside the `React.render`) is not referenced.  Whatever tool you are using should have a js file that you need to also add another `<script>` tag for.

Comment: What do you mean by tool?

Answer (score 1):

Try to load your script after your div and not inside

```
<div id="tree">
</div>
<script src="/listTree/TreeNode.js"></script>
```

You need to load React also

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I get it working add the following script

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
```

and change the type to 'text/babel'

```
<script type="text/babel" src="script.js"></script>
```

and the external js file should be with

> .jsx

extension

please see working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/o0mqfzyxmbuiRXWmOK20?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

You should not place a slash before "listTree".

So your script tag should look like this:

```
<script src="listTree/TreeNode.js"></script>
```